# Weblogic 12c : JNDI lookup to fetch a path of a file on Shared drive

Tags: java, jndi, weblogic12c

I'm very new to JNDI lookup and want to understand as to what are the necessary steps, files, modifications required, to perform a lookup for a file path which is present on a shared drive. My colleague shared an example which was implemented for Websphere with res-type as java.net.URL. I need to perform a similar implementation for Weblogic.

The following are the snippets from Webshpere implementation.

**WEB-INF/web.xml**

```
<resource-ref id="32131654798797">
<description></description>
<res-ref-name>url/PAR</res-ref-name>
<res-type>java.net.URL</res-type>
<res-auth>Container</res-auth>
<res-sharing-scope>Shareable</res-sharing-scope>
</resource-ref>
```

**META-INF/resource.xml**

```
<resource-ref id="8797951454643">
<description></description>
<res-ref-name>url/PAR</res-ref-name>
<res-type>java.net.URL</res-type>
<res-auth>Container</res-auth>
<res-sharing-scope>Shareable</res-sharing-scope>
</resource-ref>
```

**META-INF/ejb-jar.xml**

```
<resource-ref id="8797951454643">
    <description></description>
    <res-ref-name>url/PAR</res-ref-name>
    <res-type>java.net.URL</res-type>
    <res-auth>Container</res-auth>
    <res-sharing-scope>Shareable</res-sharing-scope>
</resource-ref>
```

Could you provide the steps to achieve the same. I'm trying to implement this on Weblogic 12c

Comment: Can you provide some code and/or xml config to show what you are trying to do?

Comment: I can provide the one that is implemented for Websphere. would that be fine?

Comment: Yes - they will have many similarities. Edit your question to add some more detail

Comment: I have added the sample that my colleague shared with me. This implementation is for webSphere.